# Is there any danger in posting your .htaccess file on a forum?

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

As title says. I am looking for some help with my .htaccess. I have been offered help on an apache forum however before i post my .htaccess for others to see i wondered if by doing this the security of my site could be compromised in any way??

Thanks

P

Comment: Well I do not think that there might be some danger.Want to see ppl answering this

Comment: How about posting your .htaccess file first? ;)

Comment: funny but could do with some serious contributions if possible please

Comment: Depends on what is in the .htaccess file. We'd have to see it to tell for sure. Seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe?  It depends?

If you have something that includes a secure system path like the location of AuthUserFile, you might want to put in some dummy text before posting:

```
AuthUserFile /PATH_TO_FILE/
```

Most of the boiler plate stuff (ErrorDocument, hiding the .htaccess, -Indexes, etc...) though, wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This is probably the best answer that can be given. Remove any specific paths and domain names and you should usually be okay.

Comment: thanks a lot. There doesnt seem to be anything in there that looks like it shouldnt be shared but just thought i would check